# laraevl 5.4 login with username or password (both)

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I want to login using username or password in laravel 5.4, I tried some thing but nothing worked for me.

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $field = filter_var($request->input('login'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'username';
    $request->merge([$field => $request->input('login')]);
    if ($this->auth->attempt($request->only($field, 'password')))
    {
        return redirect('/');
    }
    return redirect('/login')->withErrors([
        'error' => 'These credentials do not match our records.sssss',
    ]);
}
```

I added this function in `LoginController.php` file, but I think it is not hitting this function, So how to do it ?

Comment: Just remove `exit`?

Comment: it was by mistake remain there. I removed it

Comment: isn't laravel already have default middleware to handle authentication?

Comment: @BagusTesa only if you enable it)

Comment: it provide login using either email or username, i want it with both

Answer (score 2):

Laravel already provides authentication by default. In fact everything is configured already by Laravel. You just need to do the following for setting up authentication correctly in Laravel :

- **php artisan make:auth** (this will create all the routes and view you need for authentication)
- When a user is successfully authenticated, they will be redirected to the /home URI. You can customize the post-authentication redirect location by defining a redirectTo property on the  LoginController, RegisterController, and ResetPasswordController:

  protected $redirectTo = '/';
- You can get the authenticated user in any controller by including the below code

  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

  // Get the currently authenticated user...
  $user = Auth::user();

  // Get the currently authenticated user's ID...
  $id = Auth::id();
- You can check if user is authenticated or not by using the below code

  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

  if (Auth::check()) {
      // The user is logged in...
  }
- Add the below code to your Login Controller

  public function username() { 
      return 'username'; 
   }

  if(filter_var($username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
     //user sent their email 
     Auth::attempt(['email' => $username, 'password' => $password]); 
  } else { 
     //they sent their username instead 
     Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password]); 
  }

You can read more about laravel authentication and its customization's at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication

Comment: do it provide login with both username and email ??

Comment: It provides authentication with email. However you can modify it if you want to login using username

Comment: exactly, i want login with both using username and email. Do laravel 5.4 has any inbuilt functinality for it?

Comment: Yes you can, just have a look at the official documentation, especially "Username Customization". I think it will help.

Comment: Look in: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php

Comment: By default laravel returns : public function username()
{
        return 'email';
}

Comment: You can add public function username()
{
        return 'username';
}

Comment: to your LoginController as mentioned in the official documentation

Comment: if(filter_var($username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    //user sent their email 
    Auth::attempt(['email' => $username, 'password' => $password]);
} else {
    //they sent their username instead 
    Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password]);
}

Answer (score 2):

As @Gaurav Roy mentioned, you must first create Laravel's authentication routes by typing on console `php artisan make:auth`. You will notice that in `Controllers` directory exists a directory named `Auth` with some Controllers in it. Open `LoginController` and override `username()` function and return the column you wish to authenticate with the password. In your case:

```
private $value = 'username';

public function username()
{
   return $this->value;
}
```

Now override `attemptLogin(Request $request)` function and try to login with username or email:

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    // try to login with username
    $loginWithUsername = $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->has('remember')
    );

    // if credentials with username are not valid, try with email
    if (!$loginWithUsername) {
        // replace username with email
        $this->value = 'email';
        $this->username();

        // add input value to email
        $request['email']  = $request['username'];
        unset($request['username']);

        return $this->guard()->attempt(
            $this->credentials($request), $request->has('remember')
        );
    }
    return $loginWithUsername;
}
```

Now go to `resources->views->auth`, open `login` file and replace email's input so it can accept the username. For example:

From:

```
<input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>
```

To:

```
<input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required autofocus>
```

Now you can login with username or email!

Comment: so it will login using username instaed of email ?

Comment: at first, it will try with username, if fails it will try email. If both fail, the result will be false

Answer (score 2):

Try Something like this. You should override this code in LoginController.php

```
public function login(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
       'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);

if (Auth::guard()->attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request-password], $request->remember)) {
if successfull, then redirect to intended location


   return view('level1'); 

else
    return view('manager');
}



    //if successfull, then redirect back to login with the form data
    return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email','remember'));  


}
 return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want both username and email then in your LoginController you can try something like:

```
return property_exists($this, 'username') ? $this->username : 'email';
```